# PyQtGraph, scrolling the graph in only one direction

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

in my software i have a combobox that lets the user choose if it wants to have the graph with an auto range in X, Y, both or none axis.

A results can be obtained with

```
pw1.enableAutoRange(axis="x") # or y or xy o disableAutoRange()
pw1.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=True)
```

**The main problem is that with**

```
pw1.enableAutoRange(axis="xy")
pw1.setMouseEnabled(x=False, y=True)
```

**the autoRange goes off if an user scroll the graph (that makes sense if you let the mouse enabled in both axis but not with disabled axis)**

Question: how can i set an autoRange on Y and not on X letting the user the ability to zoom - dezoom move the graph in X direction?

Related code: https://pastebin.com/Jzep4BR0

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Edited, the question is:  how can i set an autoRange on Y and not on X letting the user the ability to zoom - dezoom move the graph in X direction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's still an issue for you, but you can do it the following way (it worked for me at least):

```
pw1.enableAutoRange(axis='y')
pw1.setMouseEnabled(x=True, y=False)
```

Does this help?

Comment: No, it doesn't. Your code mainly enable the y autorange without disabling it in the X axis. I can do that with `pw1.enableAutoRange(x=False, y=True)` but the main issue remains. I bolded it in the main question

Comment: The problem is, that I cannot reproduce the error. For me the autorange does not go off, if I only set the setMouseEnabled(x=True, y=False) and scroll the graph (neither with the mouse wheel, when zooming, nor with the drag-and-drop scrolling). I made a code snippet based on the pyqtgraph official example: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e9fe8413718722e6c704db6e15fbd8ec. I changed the behaviour of the pw2 PlotWidget. Could you modify it so it works the 'bad' way?

Comment: Hello, i can't modify the code on gh. In any case here the code https://pastebin.com/Jzep4BR0 . Thanks a lot